# アイコンを設定するとAlt押し下げ時のコマンドが表示されない

Tags: vscode

エディタタイトルバーにコマンドを追加したのですが、アイコンを設定するとAlt押し下げ時のコマンドが表示されなくなります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Alt押下げ時のアイコンの設定方法が分からないので、Alt押下げ時のアイコンは設定してません。
Alt押下げ時のアイコンを設定すればAlt押下げ時のアイコンが表示されるようになるのでしょうか?
コマンドは表示されていませんが、クリックするとAlt押下げ時のコマンドが実行されてます。

なお、これらコマンド(アイコン)はエディタ分割時だけ表示されるようにしてます。
私の設定方法に何か間違いがあると思うのですが、ご指摘いただければ幸いです。
また、Alt押下げ時のアイコンの設定方法がありましたら教えていただきたいです。

追記:
アイコンをPNGで作成しているのですがSVGじゃないとだめなのでしょうか。
あとでSVGで作成して試してみたいと思います。
・・・SVGで作成しましたが駄目でした。同じ状態のままです。

```js
"commands": [
    {"command": "workbench.action.toggleEditorGroupLayout",
        "title": "分割方向切替",
        "icon":{
            "dark":  "./icon/darkicon.svg",
            "light": "./icon/lighticon.svg"
        }
    }
],
    "menus":{
        "editor/title": [
        {"when": "multipleEditorGroups",
            "command": "workbench.action.toggleEditorGroupLayout",
            "alt": "workbench.action.newWindow",
            "group": "navigation"
        }
```

Comment: 「エディタタイトルバーにコマンドを追加した」　←この部分はどの方法を使ったのかを [edit] から追記いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0):

いろいろ考えすぎてしまって、単純なことに気が付きませんでした。
解決したので「単純なこと」と言えますが、質問する前まではあちこち検索したり、コードを書き換えたり、なかなか思うようにいかず困ってました。
「この部分はどの方法を使ったのか」という言葉で、第3者的にコードを見直せたことで解決に至りました。

コードを追記してふと思いついたのですが、commandにAlt側のコマンドを追加して
`"workbench.action.newWindow"` にアイコンを設定したらできました!!^^v
お騒がせしてすみません。これにて解決とします。